# Change TD value using AJAX from another view

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I have 2 view, one is the primary to generate the reports, and the other I didn't want to open it, just I designed it with specific tables in order to fill these tables using AJAX in the main view then print it, the problem in the accessing to each `<td>` id and change its value using ajax, when I tried to alert its content, a message with Undefined appeared, any idea about how I can do that please.

[My views structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAoNn.png)

```
function FillAndPrint(arrangement) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/Home/Report_Data",
        datatype: "json",
        dataSrc: "",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { 'Arrnagement': arrangement },
        success: function (data) {
            //this just for test, the main code will change tds values from JSON file 
            $("#LD_name").html("test"); // LD_name exist on another view
            alert($("#LD_name").val()); // result is Undefined
            },
        error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  // detailed error messsage 
            alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + " " + httpRequest);
        }
    });
    }
```

if this way is impossible, please tell me which way to use.

Comment: You have to use that `data` into your page like `$('#something').html(data);` after that you can try `$("#LD_name").html("test"); alert($("#LD_name").val());`

Comment: its return JSON file and all okey, but here I didn't fill td from JSON, I set a static value, success data is accessible because it alter undefined.

Comment: `#LD_name` is not present in a page. you are retrieving that data from another page so first, you have to load that data on to your page before selecting the element.

Comment: what is the best way to load them without show that view

Comment: create a div in your main page with a class like `<div class='divtohide'></div>`, in your css type `.divtohide{display:none;}` and then load your ajax data in that div with this code `$('.divtohide').html(data);`

Comment: that works for me, thank you